# Observer Pattern Via Boost Signal2

Tags: c++, boost, signals, bind, observer-pattern

So, I've read the docs for Boost.Signal2 and I have done a bit of googling and I just haven't quite found what I needed. What I have is a controller and a view concept. The Controller will be sending data to the View for it to render. What I want is my controller to call Controller::Update and trigger the OnUpdate function in the view.

- The controller and view should be disjoint
- Signals on the **Controller** can be emitted to execute Slots in the **View**

Here is code I have tried so far:

```
class Listener {
public:
    virtual void OnUpdate() {};
};

class View :Listener
{
public:
    View(void);
    ~View(void);
    virtual void OnUpdate() override;
};

void View::OnUpdate()
{
    std::cout << "Updating in View";
}

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller(void);
    ~Controller(void);
    void Update();
};

Controller::Controller(void)
{
    // Signal with no arguments and a void return value
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
    sig.connect(boost::bind(&Listener::OnUpdate, this, _1));
    // Call all of the slots
    sig();
    system("pause");
}
```

This does not compile. I get **error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'**, but this is just because I'm using bind incorrectly.

Does anybody know how I could achieve what I want using signals/slots from boost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are quite a number of misconceptions here. I recommend you start simpler.

- the Listener base class probably needs a virtual destructor
- you cannot bind `Listener::OnUpdate` to `this` inside the `Controller` class because `Controller` is not derived from `Listener`
- You need to derive *publicly* from `Listener`
- there is no argument, so you need to pass zero placeholders (`_1` was out of place)

Here's a simple fixed-up sample

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/432cc48dc52dffdd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Listener {
public:
    virtual ~Listener() = default;
    virtual void OnUpdate() = 0;
};

class View : public Listener
{
public:
    View() = default;
    ~View() = default;
    virtual void OnUpdate() override {
        std::cout << "Updating in View\n";
    }
};

class Controller
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
public:
    Controller() {
    }

    void subscribe(Listener& listener) {
        // Signal with no arguments and a void return value
        sig.connect(boost::bind(&Listener::OnUpdate, &listener));
    }

    void DoWork() const {
        // Call all of the slots
        sig();
    }

    void Update();
};

int main() {

    View l1, l2;
    Controller c;

    c.subscribe(l1);

    std::cout << "One subscribed:\n";
    c.DoWork();

    c.subscribe(l2);

    std::cout << "\nBoth subscribed:\n";
    c.DoWork();
}
```

Which prints:

```
One subscribed:
Updating in View

Both subscribed:
Updating in View
Updating in View
```

### Computer, Simplify: Now C++ style

Perhaps a more compelling example in C++ would be:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06130146f23131cf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct View {
    void OnUpdate() { std::cout << "Updating in View\n"; }
};

class Controller {
    using UpdateHandler = boost::signals2::signal<void()>;
    UpdateHandler sig;

  public:
    Controller() {}

    void subscribe(UpdateHandler::slot_type handler) { sig.connect(handler); }
    void DoWork() const { sig(); }
    void Update();
};

int main() {

    View l1;
    Controller c;
    c.subscribe(std::bind(&View::OnUpdate, &l1));
    c.subscribe([] { std::cout << "Or we can attach a random action\n"; });

    c.DoWork();
}
```

Which prints

```
Updating in View
Or we can attach a random action
```

Comment: Added [a less  Java-esque example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06130146f23131cf) for perspective; you don't need `IObserveSomething` and `IAmADocXXXView` in order to connect to Signals2 slots.

Comment: Wow, yes this is exactly what I need! I think I was confused with who owns the listener and who is responsible for managing subscriptions. Thank you so much for helping me understand!!

Comment: You use it in case you did want to pass arguments to the handlers